# Relocate folders containing a specific file type in Windows7

Tags: command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments

How can i move all folders which contain at least one file with extension .RMT from \drwngs\test to \drwngs\firm in Windows7?

Answer (score 2):

```dos
for /d %%a in ("x:\drwngs\test\*") do dir /a-d "%%~fa\*.rmt" >nul 2>&1 && (
    move "%%~fa" "x:\drwngs\firm"
)
```

For each folder inside the source, if it contains a `.rmt` file (the `dir` command does not raise an errorlevel), move the folder to the target

Edited - To use from command line

```
for /d %a in ("x:\drwngs\test\*") do dir /a-d "%~fa\*.rmt" >nul 2>&1 &&  move "%~fa" "x:\drwngs\firm"
```

Comment: typing the script from C:\drwngs, cmd.exe returned: %%a was unexpected at this time. I modified the script to: for /d %a in ("c:\drwngs\test") do dir /a-d "%~fa\*.rmt" >nul 2>&1 && (move "%~fa" "c:\drwngs\firm")      to which cmd.exe returned:  dir /a-d "c:\drwngs\test\"*.rmt" >nul 2>&1 && (move "c:\drwngs\test" "c:\drwngs\firm")
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: The code included was intented to be included in a batch file (the reason it is multiline and `for` replaceable parameters use `%%a` instead of `%a`). Answer updated with a missing wildcard (my fault) and a command line version.

Comment: Worked as ran from batch file. Moved 1,848 files contained in 185 folders.